# Was the bombed Barzah scientific research centre inspected by OPCW in Nov 2017?

Tags: war, syria, propaganda

Was the bombed [Barzah scientific research centre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barzah_scientific_research_centre) the same as the " Barzah facility" in this [23 March 2018 OPCW report](https://www.opcw.org/fileadmin/OPCW/EC/88/en/ec88dg01_e_.pdf) stating (section 11):

> the second round
>   of inspections at the Barzah and Jamrayah facilities of the SSRC was concluded on
>   22 November 2017. ...The analysis of
>   samples taken during the inspections did not indicate the presence of scheduled
>   chemicals in the samples, and the inspection team did not observe any activities
>   inconsistent with obligations under the Convention during the second round of
>   inspections at the Barzah and Jamrayah facilities.

Comment: What other facility could this be referring to? I can't think of any other. And have you tried say searching google to find the answer? What are you doubting here?

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin Many sources are saying the targets were "chemical weapons facilities".